# Errorformat not recognizing my errors

Tags: quickfix, errorformat

I have errors which looks like this:

```
[Error] Z:\absolute\file\path.cpp(42): error C2065: 'foo': undeclared identifier
[Info] Z:\another\file\path.cpp(42): error C2050: 'foo': switch expression not integral
```

And I used the following command:

```
CompilerSet errorformat=[\a\+]\ %f(%l):\ %m
```

But it does not appear to work. The "channel" part seems to not match (`\a\+`), since if I replace it with `Error` or `Info`, I capture the related lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set errorformat=[%t%*\\a]\ %f(%l):\ %m
```

The pattern `\a\+`, is equivalent to `%*\\a` according to `:h errorformat`.

However you may want to look to see if Vim already supports your compiler of choice. Do `:compiler` then tab complete or use `<c-d>` to get a list of known compilers.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Compiler underneath is msvc, but output altered on way out of build process.